# have a trouble with batch script to copy files only once

Tags: batch-file

New to batch scripting.. 
I want to copy files from one folder(A) to another folder(B) continuously. The other software "moves" files from folder B. My script with Xcopy is continuously copying files from A to B. But When the copied  files are moved from B, script is copying again the same files to B. Script should copy files from A to B only once.

Answer (score 0):

You could have shown us the script and made things easier.

From the prompt, execute

```
xcopy /?
```

to show `xcopy` options.

I'd suggest the `/d` option would do what you need.

Comment: Good Idea! will explore this.

Comment: @echo off

:copy

xcopy /Y Source Destination >D:\log1.txt

goto copy

Answer (score 0):

Every file has an *archive* attribute. This attribute was created to determine when a file needs to be copied (well, more or less). By default, files are generated with this attribute set and any change to the file will set it again.

`xcopy` includes two switches: `/a` and `/m` that handle this attribute.

- `/a` tells `xcopy` to only copy files that have the archive attribute set
- `/m` tells `xcopy` to only copy files that have the archive attribute set and clear the attribute

You should try something like `xcopy /m "c:\sourceA\*" "c:\targetB"` This will copy files with the archive attribute set and remove the attribute from the archive.